# Does HCE Service work when screen is locked?

Tags: android, nfc, android-pay, hce

I am developing a mobile wallet application and I have a problem that I cannot make payments when screen is locked. The HostApduService not works although I put my mobile phone on the POS terminal. Do you know Google wallet make payments when the screen is locked with no password or password / pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your APDU configuration xml file that you reference in AndroidManifest.xml file, set the property "`requireDeviceUnlock`" to "`false`".  See it in this example: https://github.com/handstandsam/HandstandPay/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/apdu_config.xml

Example project: https://github.com/handstandsam/HandstandPay

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that according to the Android official documentation in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html "Current Android implementations turn the NFC controller and the application processor off completely when the screen of the device is turned off. HCE services will therefore not work when the screen is off.". So the HCE service works but NFC controller of the device not. Do you have test it?

Comment: With "requireDeviceUnlock" to "false" it beeps only. It does not prompt me to enter the pin for the screen off and locked. processCommandApdu method not called. If I know the place of the code that makes "beep" I can turn on the screen on and show user to unlockscreen. Can you help?

Comment: The NFC chip is not powered if the screen is not on. That's just a sucky Android user experience but it is how the OS works. That is what the Android docs are saying (screen off use case). You asked if the lock screen is showing on the screen (but the phone is still locked), how do you still send commands with your `HostApduService` and that answer is the `requireDeviceUnlock` field. Nothing can be sent with NFC with the screen unlit unless you have a modded version of Android or something.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As a result the screen must be on but has not to be unlocked to make HCE work (with requireDeviceUnlock=false) - Tested with a global company HCE SDK and a global bank POS terminal.